# I want to disable it as soon as a value from dropdown has been selected

Tags: drop-down-menu

I have a drop down menu with a few options and I want to enable the selected portion and disable the other portions once I select a value from dropdown using PHP.

Comment: Can you show the code you have tried?

Answer (score 1):

Are you looking for something like this?

```js
var ddl = $('#test');

ddl.on('change', function()
  {
    if (ddl.find('selected').val() != '')
      {
        ddl.prop('disabled', true);
      }
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id='test'>
    <option value=''>select</option>
    <option value=''>a</option>
    <option value=''>b</option>
    <option value=''>c</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to achieve what you  want from PHP. PHP is a server side language. What you want is client side interaction.The code snippet by @Vimalan is appropriate.

Comment: :I have two buttons "Submit" and "Add". Is it possible for to disable the one button if another button is clicked?